# Angularjs terminal directive preventing execution of ng-bind

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am intercepting an ng-click action (deletion) with a directive called confirmPlease. 
This works well. The directive is terminal and prevents execution of ng-click until a confirmation dialogue is displayed. 
The original clickAction is then attached to the confirm-event.

But now the problem is, that i would like to translate the button those directives are attached to. But binding is halted as soon as I attach me confirmPlease directive.

I tried various priority values but i cannot get it to work.

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/akiiiii/f8QeD/21/

As soon as i remove the:

```
tplEl.attr("data-confirm-please", "getTexts('delete')");
```

the button works.
Thank you in advance for taking a look

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but this works:
http://jsfiddle.net/f8QeD/32/

I basically moved your `.attr(..)` to after the element was compiled.

But this breaks your `ng-click` handlers, so I added another compile step after adding attributes:
http://jsfiddle.net/f8QeD/33/

And now it works. I guess this is a bug in Angular, where it can't compile both handlebar expressions and attributes at the same time. You should raise an issue on their github page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input abject_error, but I'm afraid with this version none of the attached attributes are compiled. The button text is there, but the functions are not called on click.